# Predict winning number depending on results?

Tags: ruby

I want to generate the most probable number depending on the latest lottery results I have on a CSV.

I have this script:

```
h = Hash.new
f = File.open('numbers.csv', "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  numbers = line.split
  numbers.each { |w|
    if h.has_key?(w)
      h[w] = h[w] + 1
    else
      h[w] = 1
    end
  }
}

# sorteamos el hash por valor, y lo pintamos según la concurrencia
h.sort{|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}.each { |elem|
  puts "\"#{elem[0]}\" tiene #{elem[1]} concurrencia"
}
```

That will tell me which numbers have the most ocurrencies.
I want to "sample" a number depending on these results that has the most probability.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to select the item from your hash which has the most hits? Or that you would like to pick an item from the hash at random, weighted by the hash values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Ruby has a built-in elegant way of doing this. You can treat your hash as a bunch of bins, where the number of occurrences of each number is the bin size. Then you can calculate the total bin width, get a random sample, and iterate to find out which bin the sample lands in.

```
def weighted_sample h
  weight = h.values.reduce(:+)
  sample = rand weight
  h.each do |n, w|
    return n if sample < w
    sample -= w
  end
end

Array.new(10) { weighted_sample({1 => 8, 2 => 4, 3 => 2}) }
# [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Tip:** there's a much nicer way to build that hash

```
h = Hash.new 0
# ...
h[w] += 1
```